# Continuous Image of a profinite group into $T=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: profinite-groups

Let $f : G \to T$ be a continuous homomorphism from a profinite group into $T= \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

According to a book I am reading, $f(G)$ is totally disconnected.

Why is this true? The book doesn't explain it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is finite here is a proof

The torus has an open neighborhood $V$ of zero, which contains no non-trivial subgroups of $S^1$. Since $G$ is a profinite group, there exists an open normal subgroup $U$ of $G$ satisfying $U\subseteq \chi^{-1}(V)$. This implies $U\subseteq Ker(\chi)$. So, the map $\chi$ factors throw $G/U$, which is finite (G is compact and U open). It follows the image is also finite.